# Parenting Bones to IK Control Bone- Are Transforms inherited?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, constraints, inverse-kinematics

I have a Problem with my IK.
I parented the Circled Bone to the IK Rig's Control Bone (Facing toward Camera). But the Circled Bone inherits weird transformtations.
When I move the Control Bone in X, the Circled Bone doesnt only move in X, but also rotates around the Control Bone's Y Axis, As if it inherited some Transformations from this Parent Bone (=Control Bone).
I tried using Constraints on the Parent Bone (Control Bone), But I need the Circled Bone to Rotate Around its Z Axis and when I use a Z Axis Constraint on the Parent Bone it doesn't work out.

See the first transformation (Move along -x) here:

[image]

See the Second transformation (move along +X) here:

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to achieve, and what are the bone constraints of the parent and the circled bone in your example.

Comment: I guess my basic question is: Can I see whether a IK Rig is influencing a specific bone, and i yes where can I control it?
Thank you for your feedback though!